# CSP: frame-ancestor failing

Tags: iis, content-security-policy

I have a strange problem with an IIS hosted website. The site has two bindings. Lets call them https://abc.xxx.com and https://def.yyy.com.

I have set the following for CSP

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.xxx.com
```

There is a page on that website that has an iframe with src="https://abc.xxx.com/somepath". When I access the page from the first URL binding the iframe loads fine. If I access it with the second I get:

```
Refused to frame 'https://abc.xxx.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.xxx.com
```

Now for the even weirder part. If I change my CSP to include the second binding like below, the iframe loads.

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.xxx.com https://*.yyy.com
```

I can't explain why this is the case. The iframe src is clearly using the first binding. Why would it require the second one in order to work? There is no redirect going on from one binding to another. I tried removing the wildcards and putting the whole binding but there was no change.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Are https://abc.xxx.com and https://def.yyy.com two different URLs? if so you need to set them in Content-Security-Policy.

Comment: They are two different URL bindings for the same IIS site. Why is the second one required as the src of the iframe is pointing to the first one?

Comment: They are on the same site does not mean they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing weird, have a look at the scheme below. I have just removed subdomains and `https://` scheme, they both don't matter in this case:

```
 xxx.com in address bar
 frame-ancestors 'self' xxx.com
.---<iframe src= xxx.com/path ---.
| frame-ancestors 'self' xxx.com |
|                                |
'--------------------------------'
```

Iframe is loaded because `xxx.com` in the address bar falls under `frame-ancestors 'self' xxx.com` (under both of sources: `'self'` and `xxx.com`).

```
 yyy.com in address bar
 frame-ancestors 'self' xxx.com
.---<iframe src= xxx.com/path ---.
| frame-ancestors 'self' xxx.com |
|                                |
'--------------------------------'
```

Iframe is not loaded because `yyy.com` in the address bar does not fall under either `'self'` or `xxx.com`.

Just a violation message:

```
Refused to frame 'https://abc.xxx.com/' because an ancestor violates
the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.xxx.com
```

is a little bit misleading and should be treated as:

```
Refused to frame 'https://abc.xxx.com/' because an ancestor HTTPS://YYY.com violates
the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.xxx.com
```

Comment: Thank you! What is misleading is not this message but rather this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors